# Userform objects changing size/zoom on different monitors

Tags: vba, userform

A VBA UserForm is displaying its objects with different size/resolution on other people's monitors than what is showing on my current monitor.

I am unable to change any "User Interface Options" for dual monitor setups in the Excel options menu (the tab isn't even available in the version of Excel I am using), getting DPI information from the monitor and adjusting, and adjusting the width and height with the application settings but nothing has worked so far.

Please let me know any other potential solutions to this issue.
Thank you!
[image: This is the version showing on my monitor (what I want everyone to see)]

[image: This is the version showing on other monitors (not what I want)]

Comment: Userforms AFAIK use points not pixels for their positioning. Also, have you tried arranging the pictures in the initialize sub of the UF?

Comment: Are the text below the icons an image? Send them back behind the icon image. Images seem to be zoomed in. Are the **PictureSizeMode** set to `3 - fmPictureSizeModeZoom`? Change it and test.